# Stripe - Max Quantity Subscription

Tags: stripe-payments

To clarify, this is a question for Stripe (an online payment processing app) API.

I want to limit the max quantity of a product depending on the subscription. So, lets say I have sub_id_1 and sub_id_2. I want to limit sub_id_1 product quantity to have a maximum purchase of 3 items, while sub_id_2 to have a maximum purchase of 1 item.

I do not have any code to show since it is just a API problem, but from what I get from the docs, it is possible to alter the quantity of the product in a subscription. However, I am not sure if it is possible to limit the quantity instead.

I would appreciate any kind of answers, feedbacks, or suggestions!

Comment: Are you referring to limiting the quantity in a single transaction, or limiting the quantity that can be accumulated into a subscription across one or more transactions?

Comment: @ed2 Accumulated quantity. So, since I am using Stripe customer portal to let the customer update their subscription details, I want to limit that change so that the quantity of that subscription is lower than a set value. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: I don't know if the customer portable is customizable in that way. I would recommend connecting to #stripe on IRC to ask the devs there how they would recommend implementing your proposed restriction.

Comment: @ed2 I see, thanks a lot for the suggestion! Will try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a way to do this with Stripe's API, so you'd have to handle enforcing this limitation within your application.